# Application.Interactive = True fails

Tags: vba, excel

In the worksheet SelectionChange event I set :

```
Application.Interactive = False
.... do work
Application.Interactive = True
```

For some reason Interactive is not getting set back to true, even though I know the code is being executed.

Excel 2013

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah wait up ... I find the problem is only the case when Autofilter is on.  (same behaviour in 2010 by the way)

Comment: Getting closer - I have a function marked as 'Application.Volatile', if I comment out this line - it works ok.  The function is used in column heading cells to display the active auto filter equation.

Comment: Red herring - see answer comments

Comment: This might help someone. For me, .Interactive = False failed. I fixed it by immediately preceding with .Interactive = True (even tho' already True).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

    Debug.Print Application.Interactive
    Application.Interactive = False
    Debug.Print Application.Interactive
    Application.Interactive = True
    Debug.Print Application.Interactive

End Sub
```

Doesn't fail for me... Try that and [**see more here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841248.aspx)

Since you've discovered the reason for failing the conclusion could be that the [`Application.Volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195441.aspx) needs to be set to false on a function that uses it because the `Interactive` mode blocks the user  interface and the `Volatile` calculates things based on user input. While the user input is blocked you can't expect a function that evaluates the user input to work. One excludes the other - hope that makes sense.

Additionally, check your `on error resume next` or `on error goto <label>` statements as the would cause skipping some of the code therefore the `Application.Interactive = True` would have never get executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but see comments above. Something to do with Application.Volatile

Comment: This turned out to be a red herring.  I found that I had a procedure that setting ON ERROR RESUME NEXT, and after a serious error the code was stepping over statements in the calling procedure (Application.Interactive=True) without reporting further errors.  In other words Application.Interactive=True was throwing an error because of a previous error but I was not seeing the error message and it appeared that the statement was not working.

Comment: @brigzy great I am glad youve solved the problem. Ill update the answer to reflect that

Comment: @RichardBriggs "Application.Interactive=True was throwing an error because of a previous error" -- Can you explain? Why did Application.Interactive throw an error?

Comment: @RichardBriggs If .Volatile was a red herring, why did you leave it in your answer?

Comment: @RichardBriggs "Application.Volatile needs to be set to false on a function that uses it because the Interactive mode blocks the user interface and the Volatile calculates things based on user input - hope that makes sense." - That doesn't make sense to me. .Volatile handles values entered into worksheet formulas, not interactive user-input.